# How to recognize or get the unique field name from mongoose driver with multiple unique fields

Tags: mongodb, validation, mongoose

I have created the user schema where email and the username is unique. When I try to save a user with the username that already exists in the collection then the following error return by the MongoDb(mongoose driver).

```
"error": {
        "driver": true,
        "name": "MongoError",
        "index": 0,
        "code": 11000,
        "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: todo.users index: username_1 dup key: { : \"sak\" }"
    }
```

But when I try to save a user with the email address that already exists in the collection then the same type of error return by the MongoDb(mongoose driver) like this.

```
"error": {
    "driver": true,
    "name": "MongoError",
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: todo.users index: email_1 dup key: { : \"sachin121@gmail.com\" }"
}
```

This is the my user schema -

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        email: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            trim: true,
            index: true,
            unique: true,
            required: true
        },
        username: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            trim: true,
            index: true,
            unique: true,
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            bcrypt: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior.. your error type is `duplicate key` as both fields marked as unique indexes. Look at the error message which shows you the field that it failed for. Alternative, the mongoose error should return a `path` property which points to the specific field that caused the error (guess that what you asked for). For further information please take a look at mongoose docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Comment: I know the error message show the field that is failed but how can i return the error message by checking something like error_field == 'email or username'?

Answer (score 1):

To get the error index (aka email or username), you'll have to parse the `errormsg` string and take the property that is mentioned after the `index:` word in the error message.

There was an issue about this specific discussion and this answer was suggested. Take a look at the issue [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2129)

There is a node module that takes care of this [mongoose-unique-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator) so you can use it and get the error as a regular validation error :

```
{

    message: 'Validation failed',

    name: 'ValidationError',

    errors: {

        username: {

            message: 'Error, expected `username` to be unique. Value: `JohnSmith`',

            name: 'ValidatorError',

            kind: 'unique',

            path: 'username',

            value: 'JohnSmith'

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this `MongoError` type, you can use [mongoose-unique-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator) which checks for in unique keys in the existing documents if they already exist. In your schema as use this plugin as:

```
import { Schema } from "mongoose";
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true,
        index: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true,
        index: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        bcrypt: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    }
});

UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, {
    type: 'mongoose-unique-validator',
    message: 'Error, expected {PATH} to be unique.'
});
```

Here, you can set custom message and also can change the error type from `MongoError` but it has a limitation as mentioned in the doc of this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator#user-content-caveats).

> Because we rely on async operations to verify whether a document
>   exists in the database, it's possible for two queries to execute at
>   the same time, both get 0 back, and then both insert into MongoDB.
>
> Outside of automatically locking the collection or forcing a single
>   connection, there's no real solution.
>
> For most of our users this won't be a problem, but is an edge case to
>   be aware of.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the plugin. Clean, it is.